# Как запретить повторное использование команды start - telebot

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

мне нужно как-то запретить двойное использование команды `/старт`
Я пытался сделать но не получилось, вот мой пример кода:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])  
def start(message):  
    x = True  
    if x == True:  
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "123")
        x = False
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы уже запустили бота!")
```

Comment: это не ответ на твой вопрос, но исходя из личного опыта лучше юзай айограм. вот подробные статьи для знакомства https://mastergroosha.github.io/telegram-tutorial-2/quickstart/

Comment: а в чём он лучше?

Comment: он шустрее и стабильнее сам по себе и, на мой взгляд, проще